# Grant IUSR Rights to Use PowerShell Stop-Process Command?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have a PHP script that runs a Powershell `Stop-Process` command through `shell_exec()`.  PHP runs as IUSR.  When I run the script, I receive an access denied error message.  If I run the command in PowerShell using my Administrator account, it works as expected.

How do I grant IUSR the ability to execute `Stop-Process` in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution to grant IUSR the specific privileges to execute `Stop-Process`, but I was able to get around this by changing the "Anonymous Authentication" user associated with the kill script from `IUSR` to `Administrator`.

In IIS 8.5, go to *Sites->My Site->Folder Name*.  On the main panel, click on *Authentication* under *IIS*.  Right click on *Anonymous Authentication* and then click on *Edit*.

You can set the "Anonymous Authentication" value at any level of your IIS app; from the site level to the sub-directory level.  I recommend only changing the value from `IUSR` to `Administrator` on the directory that actually hosts your kill script.  Changing it for the whole site might create problems for other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some information that suggests if you add a limited user to the `Performance Monitor Users` group and grant it debug privileges, it will be able to terminate processes.

You might consider something a bit less risky though, like running another web app as a user with those rights, that can only be accessed from the local machine. Then make your PHP app do a web request to the internal app to do it's killin'.

If you're trying to kill only a specific process this lets you further limit the impact because the internal app could be designed to only kill that one thing.

Other ways to achieve a similar separation is to have for example a scheduled task that looks for a file with specific content in a specific directory, when it sees it, it kills a process and deletes the file. `IUSR` can be given permission to create files in that directory as a way to trigger this. This method is very easy to implement but isn't synchronous.